# Can model start over-fitting and re-correct itself

Tags: overfitting, recurrent-neural-network

This is a general question not related to specific model. So I am not sharing any code with this.

I had seen RNN models over-fitting and loss starts increasing on dev data-set,  I was wondering once a model start over-fitting can it learn going forward and can loss decrease after some iterations of learning or it is good to stop it from further training as you see loss increasing.